# Powershell Date math

Tags: powershell

I am trying to determine when 1 set date is greater then or equal to a random date.

```
$2WeeksFuture = $null
# Calculate desired date 2 weeks from today
$2WeeksFuture = (Get-Date).AddDays(14)
# Convert to DateTime and apply formatting
$2WeeksFuture = (Get-Date -Date $2WeeksFuture -Format ("MM-dd-yy"))

$TimeMath | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($User in $GSuspend ) {
        If ((Get-Date -Date $2WeeksFuture -Format ("MM-dd-yy")) -ge (get-date -date ($User.creationTime) -Format ("MM-dd-yy"))) {
            Write-Host "$(Get-Date -Date $2WeeksFuture -Format ("MM-dd-yy")) -ge $(get-date -date ($User.creationTime) -Format ("MM-dd-yy"))"
        }
    }
}
```

Wrong results

```
02-07-23 -ge 01-08-20
02-07-23 -ge 01-30-19
02-07-23 -ge 01-30-19
02-07-23 -ge 01-30-19
02-07-23 -ge 01-30-19
02-07-23 -ge 01-30-19
02-07-23 -ge 01-30-19
```

I have tried lots of combinations and it does not work.

Comment: Comparing dates can only be done correctly if you *don't* get strings involved, or when you do, parse these into `[DateTime]`s first (*not* the other way around). What's in `$TimeMath`? What's in `$GSuspend`? What's the type of `$user.creationTime`?

Comment: I will reformat my question. Great observation. but even $2WeeksFuture is coming as string.
@JeroenMostert

Comment: Don't worry about the date format until you want to display it or read it from a file or string. `Get-Date` returns a DateTime object that can be compared directly with another DateTime object without regard for culture/formatting. Additionally, the DateTime object has methods that can be used to determined the amount of time between two DateTimes, or to compute a DateTime that is a specified interval away from another DateTime.

Comment: The `-Format` parameter makes `Get-Date` output _strings_ instead of `[DateTime]` objects. Remove `-Format ("MM-dd-yy")` from both calls and it'll work

Comment: No, `$2WeeksFuture` is a `[DateTime]` (initially, at least). When displaying this it gets formatted as a string, but you can verify it's not one with `(Get-Date).AddDays(14).GetType()`. It's the other things that you're comparing it with that should be converted (through `[DateTime]::ParseExact()`, for example: `[DateTime]::ParseExact('02-27-23', 'MM-dd-yy', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MathiasR.Jessen and @JeroenMostert mention, you already have `DateTime` object. e.g.

```
$2WeeksFuture = $null
# Calculate desired date 2 weeks from today
$2WeeksFuture = (Get-Date).AddDays(14)

PS C:\> $2WeeksFuture.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType
```

Using the switch `-Format ("MM-dd-yy")` converts it into a `String` object:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Date -Date $2WeeksFuture -Format ("MM-dd-yy")).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Performing a string comparison of dates will not work, the same way that putting in strings:

```
if("Tomorrow" -gt "Yesterday"){..}
```

Will not work. Instead, you should use the `DateTime` objects themselves (which have the right underlying conditional logic) to perform the comparison.

You have half the hard work done, converting the information/strings into `DateTime` objects. Now you only need to remove the formatting portion in the `if` statement to make sure you don't convert back into strings. e.g.

```
$2WeeksFuture = $null
# Calculate desired date 2 weeks from today as a DateTime object
$2WeeksFuture = (Get-Date).AddDays(14)

$TimeMath | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($User in $GSuspend ) {
        If ($2WeeksFuture -ge (Get-Date -Date ($User.creationTime))) {
            Write-Host "$(Get-Date -Date $2WeeksFuture -Format ("MM-dd-yy")) -ge $(get-date -date ($User.creationTime) -Format ("MM-dd-yy"))"
        }
    }
}
```